# What are the ruins in Turkey near Kömürcü Köyü?

Tags: archaeology, turkey

I am curious and I would like to know what the ruins are near Kömürcü Köyü in Turkey ([38°15'27.8"N 34°33'05.5"E | 38.257711,34.551535](http://maps.google.com/?q=38.257711,34.551535))?

[image: ruins near Kömürcü Köyü]

I tried to search but I found nothing. It looks like ancient construction, but maybe it's nothing.

Comment: Could you add pictures of the ruins? Google says [Hittite Monuments](https://www.hittitemonuments.com/golludag/). [Also see this](https://www.tripmondo.com/turkey/nigde/komurcu/)

Comment: See also: https://vici.org/vici/29091/

Comment: Looks like remains of a Roman camp.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[@tohuwawohu](https://history.stackexchange.com/users/3257/tohuwawohu) and [@NSNoob](https://history.stackexchange.com/users/15625/nsnoob) seem to have nailed this in comments. The link from vici.org has Neo-Hittite ruins at 38.259163,34.541790:

[image: vici.org map]

and OP's coordinates are in blue for comparison:

[image: Google Earth map]

The former claims within 5 metres and the separation seems more like 500+ metres but some difference might be accounted for by different datums.

From [Hittite Monuments](https://www.hittitemonuments.com/golludag/) - ie first link in Comments:

> Göllüdağ is a large fortified mountain top (2172 m.) settlement of Neo-Hittite period. It is near the village of Kömürcü in Gölcük, Niğde. The settlement dates to the end of 8th century BCE. The ruins are located right next to the crater lake of the inactive volcano. Two large portal lions, known as the Göllüdağ Lions, were found at the south gate of a 112x228 meters sized building that is thought to be the palace. The lions are currently in the Kayseri Museum. Another portal lion and a couple of unfinished sphixes from Göllüdağ are in the Niğde Museum. Göllüdağ excavations were initially made by Remzi Oğuz Arık in 1934. Further excavations were carried out by Burhan Tezcan in 1968-69 and Wolfgang Schirmer in 1992-94.

Comment: Neo Hittites aren't Hittites, but some were related to them. Also, I got the impression that Komurcu Kaletepe was a different, older site.

Comment: Nevermind, Komurcu is also the name of the nearby town.

Answer (score 4):

That's the most prominent site in the Gollu Dag Archaeological Complex. Its a city from the Neo-Hittite Period, which falls roughly in the first half of the Iron Age. The region is archaeologically significant because it is rich in obsidian deposits. There are hundreds of sites dating from the Paleolithic and Neolithic periods, when obsidian was the most sought after raw material. Komurcu Kaletepe is another prominent site in Gollu Dag. The well known Neolithic site of Asikli Hoyuk is not far away.

Source: [Göllü Dag (Central Anatolia): obsidian sources, workshops and trade](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1179/2042458215Y.0000000020?needAccess=true)

Another source identifying it as Neo Hittite: [Cappadocia Explorer. August, 2009 article in Turkish](http://www.cappadociaexplorer.com/detay.php?id=217&cid=69)

Comment: Why do you think that this particular site belongs to the Neo-Hittite period? The paper you link does not seem to mention this exact location.

Comment: "The largest and best-known ancient site within the
survey area is the fortified Neo-Hittite site SITUATED ADJACENT TO THE PRECIPITATION FED LAKE [caps mine] within
the main Go¨llu¨ Dag˘ volcanic crater..." It's a conclusion that I reached based on this statement, google maps, and the most popular images of Gulu Dag on Google; the "town", and the crater lake next to it. I haven't geographically verified the "main Gulu Dag Volcano crater", which would positively identify it as this.